# Wrong eUID in `/proc/PID/status` when SETUID is used

Tags: permissions, linux-kernel, proc, signals, setuid

While doing a wargame challenge, I ran into an issue with permissions. The info given by `/proc/PID/status` is not in adequation with the permissions that should be given to the processus.

I am user user1. I am supposed to use a program which is SETUID:

```
-r-sr-x---  1 user2 user1       6297 Jun 20  2013 program
```

So it should execute with the effective UID of user2.

I'm temporarily stopping the program just after launch, to prevent it from terminating:

```
~/program "test" &
PID=$!
kill -SIGSTOP $PID
echo $PID
```

Then, I `cat /proc/$PID/status`, and I see:

```
Uid:    1003    1003    1003    1003
Gid:    1003    1003    1003    1003
```

The IDs are:

```
$ id user1
uid=1003(user1) gid=1003(user1) groups=1003(user1)
$ id user2
uid=1035(user2) gid=1035(user2) groups=1035(user2),1003(user1)
```

Given the manual (`man 5 proc`), `/proc/$PID/status` should give `Uid, Gid: Real, effective, saved set, and filesystem UIDs (GIDs).`

But here, the process has the effective ID of user1 whereas **it should have the effective ID of user2**.

I thought this might be because I stop the program too early, so I tried to attach `gdb` to it, and continue execution until it actually executes code from the `main` function of `program` (sources are given), but the effective UID given by `/proc/$PID/status` is still the one of user1 and not of user2.

Am I missing something?

Edit: remove the source of the challenge, I'm probably not authorized to post it.

Comment: @chaos Source added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are too early, if you wait until the UIDs are changed then your process runs as `user2`. This worked for me:

```
./program "test" &
PID=$!
sleep 0.0005
kill -SIGSTOP $PID
grep ^Uid /proc/$PID/status
```

Another try is to add a delay with `usleep()` and send the `SIGSTOP` later during that sleep. Then the programm runs with `user2` as effective uid. You can check that, but without attaching with `gdb` or `strace`. Most probably it's some kind of linux kernel interna, that the process needs some time to change the UIDs.

When running the process from a terminal the `execve()` syscall is called; from the manpage:

> If the set-user-ID bit is set on the program file pointed to by
>   filename, [...] and  the calling process is not being ptraced, then
>   the effective user ID of the calling process is changed to that of the
>   owner of the program file.

When you attach `gdb` to the process, you will not see the uid of `user2`, because you're `ptrace`ing the process, as described in the manual page above. Or else you could attach to a `sudo`-process and gain root permissions.

However, this program never gets a segmentation fault (`SIGSEGV`), unless you would force one with `kill -SIGSEGV $PID`. **IF** your programm gets a `SIGSEGV` the `launch_debugger()` routine is called. This will call a `gdb` and as argument just your `program` binary with without any argument, which will replace the current running process. So in the debugger will have priviledges of `user2` and therefore you can do what you want in there, with `user2`'s permissions.

You can then, for example, do the following inside `gdb`:

```
(gdb) file bash
Reading symbols from /bin/bash...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /bin/bash
user2@host:~$ id
uid=1035(user2) gid=1003(user1) groups=1035(user2),1003(user1)
```

Now, consider the same binary with a setuid bit and the owner is root.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, it exactly solved my problem. I simply didn't think of `sleep 0.0005`, and I suspected that I was lowering the permissions by attaching `gdb`, but I cound't find documentation about this. I saw the man page of `execve`, but I didn't knew that `gdb` is using `ptrace` (mostly because I was unaware of what `ptrace` actually does). Now that you mention it, it's obvious.

Comment: @vmarquet sry for the editwar, but deleting the essential part of my answer is not the correct way, I changed the username as you wanted and I will delete all my comments regarding the challenge.

Comment: ok, sorry, as long as there is no mention of anything that can identify the challenge (program name or user names), then it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Is the program running on a filesystem that honors the `setuid` bit on files (`mount -o nosuid`)?

If I were debugging this, I would print the output of `getuid()` and `geteuid()` on program startup, to see whether the `setuid` bit is being honored.

Comment: I don't have enough access to the system to check for this. But it's the principle of wargames to exploit a SETUID program with a vulnerability. If they were using `mount -o nosuid`, the challenges would be impossible.